# Command prompt undefined reference to everything

Tags: c++, command-line, undefined-reference

I am trying to build an application which takes the users input, puts it into a vector/database, and outputs the results.  When I input  the code into my windows command prompt compiler it just get it gives me a path C:/users/app/data/local/temp and then an undefined reference error to practically everything,cin,cout etc. It was initially only giving me the usual errors, but when I removed the errors it gave me this, whereas if I was to remove a semi-colon it would give me just one error. Any ideas on what might be causing this??

MP3.H

```
#define MP3_H
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class MP3
{

 public:

   MP3();//constructor
   MP3(string,string,int,int,string);
   ~MP3();

  string getName() const;
  string getSongName() const;
  int getDuration() const;
  int getReleaseYear() const;
  string getReview() const;

  private:
  string artistMP;
  string songMP;
  int duationMP;
  int releaseyearMP;
  string reviewMP;
}
#endif
```

MP3.cpp

```
#include "MP3.h"



MP3::MP3();
MP3::MP3(string artist,string  song,int duration,int releaseyear,string review){

 artistMP=artist;
 songMP=song;
 durationMP=duration;
 releaseyearMP=releaseyear;
 reviewMP=review;

}
~MP3::MP3();

string MP3::getName()const;{
return artistMP;
}

string MP3::getSongName()const;{
return songMP;
}

int MP3::getDuration()const;{
return durationMP;
}

int MP3::getReleaseYear()const;{
return releaseyearMP;
}

string MP3::getReview()const;{
return reviewMP;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<vector>
#include "MP3.h"


void  fillVector(vector<MP3>&);//5

void print (const vector<MP3>&);//7

int main( )

{

vector<MP3> myRecord;

fillVector(myRecord);
print(myRecord);

return 0;
}


void fillVector(vector<MP3> & newMyRecord){//22

cout<<"How many songs in the playlist baby";
int recordSize;
cin>>recordSize;

 for(int i=0;i<recordSize;i++)

{
 string artist;
  string song;
 int duration;
 int releaseyear;
 string review;

 cout<<"Enter Artist Name:";
 cin>>artist;
 cout<<"Enter Song Name:";
 cin>>song;
 cout<<"Enter Song Duration(in seconds):";
 cin>>duration;
 cout<<"Enter Release Year:";
 cin>>releaseyear;
 cout<<"Enter Brief Review:";
 cin:review;

MP3 newMP3(artist,song,duration,releaseyear,review);
newMyRecord.push_back(newMP3);
cout<<endl;


}
cout<<endl;
}


void print (const vector<MP3>&newMyRecord)//58

{
unsigned int size = newMyRecord.size();
for (unsigned int i=0;i<size;i++){

cout<<"Artist:"<< newMyRecord[i].getName()<<endl;
cout<<"SongName:"<< newMyRecord[i].getSongName()<<endl;
cout<<"Duration:"<< newMyRecord[i].getDuration()<<endl;
cout<<"ReleaseYear:"<< newMyRecord[i].getReleaseYear()<<endl;
cout<<"Review:"<< newMyRecord[i].getReview()<<endl;
}

}

};
```

TIA

Comment: You probably need to show the command line you used, and a small sample of the error messages (5 or so).  The chances are that you've somehow not specified which libraries to use, or you've specified libraries that don't exist, or something along those lines.

Comment: mp3.h is missing `#ifndef MP3_H` at the top.

Comment: "input the code into my windows command prompt compiler" -- ummm... what?

Answer (score 1):

Building a program occurs in (at least) two stages, compilation and linking. Undefined references are linker errors. If you get linker error it implies that compilation was successful. But if you have compiler errors (e.g. bad syntax to do with semi-colons) then linking doesn't happen so you don't see any linker errors (like undefined references).